# Vuejs not Working when append element to Fullcalender

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Hello when i append some custom button to fullcalender event it not working with vuejs methods.

it is working with core javascript i want to working with vuejs methods how i can do it?

this is my code:

```
eventRender(info) {
        // console.log(info)
        $(info.el).find(".fc-content").append(`
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" style=" float: right; top: 10px; right: 10px; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; ">
                            <button @click="vuejsMehtodName('Unpaid')" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-secondary">Unpaid</button>
                            <button @click="vuejsMehtodName('Unseen')" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-secondary">Unseen</button>
                            <button @click="vuejsMehtodName('Cancel')" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
          `);
      },
```

i tried @click.native to but same result! how i can fix it?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solve my problem with that code,
as i told you i'm using fullcalendar and i append some button to events:

```
        // console.log(info)
        $(info.el).find(".fc-content").append(`
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" style=" float: right; top: 10px; right: 10px; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; ">
                            <button id="Unpaid" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-secondary">Unpaid</button>
                            <button id="Unseen" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-secondary">Unseen</button>
                            <button id="Cancel" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
          `);
      },
```

you must add id to buttons (Unseen,Unpaid,Cancel) after that in eventClick method you must check it wich element clicked you can find it with id like that

```
eventClick(info) {
        if(info.jsEvent.toElement.id=='Unpaid' || info.jsEvent.toElement.id=='Unseen' || info.jsEvent.toElement.id=='Cancel'){
 this.vuejsMehtodName(info.jsEvent.toElement.id)
 }else{
  // here mean when we click any where on event exept (buttons)
 }
}
```

after that on your methods you need to create that method (vuejsMehtodName) you can do any thing you want.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
eventRender(info) {
        // console.log(info)
        $(info.el).find(".fc-content").append(`
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" style=" float: right; top: 10px; right: 10px; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; ">
                            <button @click="vuejsMehtodName('Unpaid')" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-secondary">Unpaid</button>
                            <button @click="vuejsMehtodName('Unseen')" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-secondary">Unseen</button>
                            <button @click="vuejsMehtodName('Cancel')" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
          `);
      },
```

You got some errors in the syntax. Try it like that.

Comment: no for example you had vuejsMehtodName('Cancel'); there you need to remove the ;

Comment: i remove it but same result, not access to the method i dont know why maybe it is about fullcalendar, because it access to core javascript function not vuejs method.

Comment: thats all i can see from the code you posted. If you want more help you need to show more code.

Comment: what code you eman exactily? if you are used Fullcalendar you can get the problem the problem i think with fullcalendar but i dont know how i can do it! because @click not working but onclick working...
https://fullcalendar.io/docs

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: i have a large commponent connected with api, but i found this he has same problem:
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-component-method-not-being-run-on-event-in-dynamic-html/8165
https://jsfiddle.net/arifhussain/awpLfzpv/